# Problem with attribute field in rasterizing tool QGIS

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I am trying to rasterize a vector layer using the "rasterize tool" in QGIS...
The problem is that there is no "attribute fields" available to choose from (even though they exist!)... [image: print screen- attribute field]
[image: field I want to rasterize]

Comment: Two possible problems come immediately to mind. If you're dealing with a shapefile that is an invalid field name - can't have any spaces. The other is what datatype is that field? I believe it would have to be numeric to work (preferably int based on visible values), and it could currently be a string depending on how it was created.

Comment: I agree with Chris, that's most likely to be the problem (either or both). It is possible that there are some issues with spatial reference. GDAL_Rasterize can use (and up to recently needed) an existing raster - if it exists ensure that the cell size suits the spatial reference of your data (or specify a different output that doesn't exist).

Comment: Thanks guys!!!!! ;) :D
I edited my table in excell and the field I wanted to rasterize wasn't defined as numeric

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you figured out, the column is not defined as 'Integer' or 'Real' type. You can use Field Calculator to add a new column of type integer and write an expression such as below to have a field you can use in conversion.

```
toint("TEXTURA LA")
```

Comment: also, as Chris pointed out, you can't have a field "TEXTURA LA" because of the space, you would need to change it to "TEXTURA_LA". Field calculator wouldn't like the space in the from field name so it's doubtful if that would run, if it did that would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem although the shapefile was ok. Going to "geoprocessing tools" and using the "gdal" "rasterize" directly instead of using the "rasterize" linked in the Qgis main menu (Raster>Conversions>Rasterize) solved the problem.